# Using a Database Context in multiple projects within the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a program that is being used to generate PDF's and documents. There are two different use cases, one being an automated process and the second being a manual process where data can be edited via a front-end app.

The solution has 2 Projects in it, the first for the automated part, and the second for the manual part.

However, since the two processes make use of the same data and templates, I've split the solution into two parts, this will allow me to set it up in a way in which I only need to maintain models/templates once.

My database context looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RefundTracker.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext()
            :base("Prod")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Referral> Referrals { set; get; }
        public DbSet<ReferralAppointment> ReferralAppointments { set; get; }
        public DbSet<ReferralPayment> ReferralPayments { set; get; }
        public DbSet<BankDetails> BankDetails { set; get; }
        
        public DbSet<ReferralAppointment_History> ReferralAppointment_History { set; get; }
        public DbSet<ReferralPayment_History> ReferralPayment_History { set ; get; }

        public DbSet<IsInUse> IsInUse { set; get; }
    }
}
```

In terms of projects, I have a project called "RefundTracker" and another called "MailMergeTPA".

The context provided above, together with all of the models, are located in the "RefundTracker" project.

I would like to make use of these models and context in the "MailMargeTPA" project as well.

I referenced the "RefundTracker" in "MailMergeTPA" project, however, no results when using the context here. (When I access a function that get a list of names for instance, I get the full list in "RefundTracker", however, I get no results when I use the same function in "MailMergeTPA".

Code Example:

```
public BankDetails GetBankDetails(Referral record)
        {
            string bName = record.bankName.Trim();
            try
            {
                BankDetails bankDetails= new BankDetails();

                List<BankDetails> bankDetails = new List<BankDetails>();

                using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
                {
                    

                    bankDetails = db.BankDetails.SingleOrDefault(a => a.BankName == bName);
                    

                }
                return bankDetails; 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
```

I would like to make use of this exact function in both projects.

Could you kindly help me with some advice? (Please go easy on me in the comments, I'm still fairly new to EF)

- I've tried referencing the project, no result.
- I've read up on interfaces, however, I'm unsure as to how I would incorporate this.

Comment: Did you make sure they're using the same source of data? Do their connection strings match? You've shown a try block in your code, but not the corresponding catch block. What do you do in the catch block?

Comment: Can you show your app settings for both projects?

Comment: Hi, the try was just a piece of code in one of the functions which I would like to reuse. The catch simply prints the error. I'll update and provide the full function - however, it's not really relevant as I was only giving an example. 

I get a null reference error. 

But as soon as I call the same function from the "RefundTracker" project I do get a response from the DB.